# Output text in TextArea box on button press

Tags: html

I simply want a button that when pressed will output any text inside a TextArea box. Something like:

```
<p id="stuff"><textarea name="" id="txt" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML = "Hello World 123";
}
</script>
```

(p.s. I know the code above doesn't work as intended, it's just an example)

Comment: "output any text inside a TextArea box"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Lokking at your code sample it appears that:

```
<p id="stuff"><textarea name="" id="txt" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea></p>
```

The paragraph is identified by `id="stuff"` while the textarea `id="text"'` This is why your code works but doesn't do what you want it to do.

The following is a working example of what I am trying to explain:

```js
function changeText() {
  document.getElementById('myTextArea').innerText = 'What ever I want to write in it.';
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="changeText();">Change text area text</button>
```